# How to Stop auto Rotation view controller in ios 8 by code

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using this method but not called-

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
```

Comment: are you using navigation controller ?

Comment: yes i using navigation controller.

Comment: then try to stop it in your navigation controller because in iOS7 and above `UINavigaitionController` is called first then `UIViewController` are called

Comment: if i removed navigation controller so i cant access push & pop others classes..

Comment: I m not asking to remove it. I m saying to control rotation from the navigation controller

Comment: Goto: [link] (stackoverflow.com/a/12955112/2775981)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
  return NO;
}
```

this code will help you to disable rotation of entire view hierarchy..

Comment: have u tested this project on real device ?

Comment: A UINavigationController will only autorotate if its root view controller is also set to autorotate. So u have to disable auto rotation feature in the rootview controller also. try disabling autorotation in rootview controller also

Comment: i have disable autorotate option from project target,and i have write autorotation method by code on main view controller class,but not called any method,